# Validity of a conditional expectation step

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

**Question:** Let $B,B^1,\dots,B^{k-1},B^k\in\mathbb{R}$ be random variables, and let us define the conditional expectations as
$$
f_{k-1}=\mathbb{E}[B|B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}]; \quad
f_k=\mathbb{E}[B|B^1,\dots,B^k],
$$
and by the law of total expectation we have
$$
f_{k-1}=\mathbb{E}[f_k|B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}].
$$
Then is the following true?
$$
\mathbb{E}[f_{k-1}f_k]
=\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_k\,|\,B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}]f_k\Big]
=\mathbb{E}[f_kf_k].
$$
I am concern about whether we are allowed to push the $f_k$ into the inner expectation. Thanks.

**Attempt:** We have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_k\,|\,B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}]f_k\Big]
&=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_k|B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}]f_k\Big|B^k\Big]\bigg] \\
&=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_kf_k|B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}]\Big|B^k\Big]\bigg] \\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_kf_k|B^k]\Big]
=\mathbb{E}[f_kf_k].
\end{align*}
Is this correct? If not, then where did my logic break? Thanks.

Comment: it's wrong........

Comment: I have given an attempt.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_k\,|\,B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}]f_k\Big]$
need not be $\mathbb{E}[f_kf_k]$

Comment: But I can show that using one extra step of the law of total expectation (as shown in my above attempt), no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these are generally not equal.  $f_k$ is a function of the random variable sequence $(B^1,\ldots, B^{k})$; it is the conditional expectation of $B$ over the $\sigma$-algebra of that sequence.

$$\underbrace{\mathsf E(f_k\mid B^1\ldots B^{k-1})~f_k}_{\text{function of }B^1\ldots B^k}\qquad\underbrace{\mathsf E(f_kf_k\mid B^1\ldots B^{k-1})}_{\text{function of }B^1\ldots B^{k-1}}$$